# Store Solver's metadata in OpenOffice's SpreadSheet

Tags: openoffice, metadata, spreadsheet

**How can you save the metadata of OpenOffice 3.0's Solver?**

I do not want to add the conditions each time I open a file in OO's SpreadSheet.
Excel by contrast saves the Solver's *Limiting conditions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that OO's native solver doesn't save the model's meta data at all. However, there is (was?) a promising extension that could save the relevant information: [scsolver](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Optimization_Solver)

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to download the extension at the moment. It was included in the Go-oo variant of OpenOffice.org as the default Solver, but as of today, it's not possible to download Go-oo b/c it is being merged with Libreoffice which doesn't include the enhanced solver.

There are still two other options you could go for: [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) offers a nice solver and saves the relevant meta data and the freeware version of the OpenOffice extension [EuroOffice Solver](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/eurooffice-solver) does so as well. Hopefully, Libreoffice will do so in the future as well (but not in the recently release version 3.3).

hth

Edit: there is a fairly old bug/ feature request for this: http://openoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93613 - and I just filed the same bug for [LibreOffice](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38948).

Comment: I close the question because I do not use OpenOffice anymore by accepting the given answer. I use LibreOffice because it is **free**. - Not sure whether such a feature is in LibreOffice yet.